Pass extra information with Heroku webhook
We have Heroku-GitHub integration for releasing our app. We also have a webhook in Heroku that sends some data when release happens. Is there any way to send an extra information by the webhook to the receiver?
I tried to utilize 'commit_description' for this purpose, but it is empty even though my releasing commit contains a description. It is located here in the webhook request body:
"data": {
  "slug": {
    "commit": "<commit>",
    "commit_description": ""
  }
}

So the questions are:

Can I pass meta info with a webhook request from Heroku to a webhook handler?
Can I set this 'commit_description' somehow?

